# An example contradicting the validity of Maschke's theorem for infinite groups.

Tags: representation-theory

I am learning representation theory of finite groups and I am in doubt about a homework problem:

Let $G = \mathbb{Z}$ and $V = \{(a_1 , a_2 , . . . )|a_i ∈ R\}$ be a vector space of infinite dimension. Define $ρ(1)(a_1 , a_2 , . . . ) =
(0, a_1 , a_2 , . . . )$ and $ρ(n)$ by composing $ρ(1)$ $n$ times. Show that this is a representation of $\mathbb{Z}$.

I cannot understand why $ρ(n)$ is surjective. It's easy to show it is injective and I need it to be invertible in order for $ρ$ to be a representation of $\mathbb{Z}$. Am I missing something here?

Comment: It's not surjective. The problem is wrong as stated. It can be fixed by replacing sequences indexed by $\mathbb{N}$ with sequences indexed by $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: You're right. This is not a representation. Whoever gave you this exercise made a booboo. $\Bbb{Z}$ needs to shift positions in a bidirectionally infinite sequences $(\ldots,a_{-2},a_{-1},a_0,a_1,a_2,\ldots)$.